# Relative day of election start is wrong saying 'yesterday' instead of '2 days ago'

Tags: bug, election

The [election page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) lists the various phases in the right margin, including when those phases start/started.

Currently the UTC time is `2018-04-04 14:35` and the election phase started at `2018-04-02 20:00` which is almost 43 hours ago.... In UTC (and EST - my local timezone, if it matters), today is Wednesday, and the Election started at 20:00 UTC on Monday, but, the election page claims that the election started `yesterday`.

[image]

Clearly, the election did not start yesterday (Tuesday), it started on Monday... 2 days ago. The relative time for the day is wrong

Comment: This is not just the election page, the same occurs all over Stack Exchange.

"yesterday" is everything from *24 hours ago* (inclusive) to *48 hours ago* (exclusive).

Comment: Part of me wonders if "fixing" this would affect Winter Bash date-sensitive hats... and April fools' toys..